# Add Team Foundation Server from Visual Studio 2012 Express

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a signed up for [Visual Studio Team Foundation Service](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/). I have setup a new Team Project. When I click the "Open new instance of Visual Studio" link, nothing happens. So, I figured I would try to add the team foundation server manually. So, I tried adding the following URL as my team foundation server. The preview shows: http://mydomain.visualstudio.com:8080/. When I attempt to add it, I get the following error:

```
TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: http://mydomain.visualstudio.com:8080/.
```

I also tried connecting to this URL http://mydomain.visualstudio.com:8080/defaultcollection with the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

try http://mydomain.visualstudio.com:8080/tfs. This format is what worked for me